Transformation .jar in .exe. As an executable file
There is such a code that converts characters from lowercase to uppercase and vice versa. You need to make a file the .jar is executable. I tried to do this through Launch4j, but the file doesn't run, there aren't even any errors. Has anyone ever encountered such a thing? My guess is that the code does not match the executable file
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите символы:");
        input = scan.next();

        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        input = new String(chars);

        System.out.println(input);
        try {
            int c = System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}

I tried to do this through Launch4j, but the file doesn't run, there aren't even any errors.

You can make your own installer

You should probably add your Launch4j configuration (xml) to the question.

The concept of "executable" .exe file is Windows-specific. Being a cross-platform programming language, Java does not support .exe file generation.
If you simply need to run java code from IntelliJ IDEA, follow these steps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-java-applications.html#run_application
